# httpd does not appear to be running and proxying cobbler, or SELinux is in the way

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu.
While doing cobbler check I am getting the following error message.

```
httpd does not appear to be running and proxying cobbler, or SELinux is in the way. Original traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cobbler/cli.py", line 252, in check_setup

    s.ping()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Changes I have done on the file `/etc/cobbler/settings` is 
server: `172.17.4.61` ( my local IP)

Answer (score 2):

The following line was missing in the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
Include conf.d/
```

Adding the above line to the Apache config file, fixes the issue.